# Node.js and SPDY ... not working?

Tags: node.js, spdy

I can't seem to get node.js (v0.8.2) to work with spdy (v1.2.1).  Here's my code in coffeescript because it's cool:

```
spdy = require 'spdy'
fs = require 'fs'

DEFAULT_PORT = 8000

DEFAULT_SERVER_OPTIONS =
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/privatekey.pem')
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/certificate.pem')
  ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/keys/certrequest.csr') 

spdy.createServer DEFAULT_SERVER_OPTIONS, (request, response) ->
    console.log 'request made...'
    response.writeHead 200
    response.write 'goodbye cruel world'
    response.end()
.listen DEFAULT_PORT
console.log 'Server running on ' + DEFAULT_PORT
```

I see "Server running on 8000", but when trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 in Chrome, I get nothing, and "request made..." never goes off.

Thanks so much guys!!

Comment: What happens if you connect to your machine's LAN IP (not 127.0.0.1)? eg: Chrome:   192.168.100.1:8000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're accessing it via HTTPS. Aka: `https://127.0.0.1:8000/` (works fine here)

SPDY is negotiated over SSL NPN, which means your server is only accessible via HTTPS protocol.